# Why doesn't Angular generate the href if *ngIf is used with an anchor tag?

Tags: angular, hyperlink

Can someone explain why the code below doesn't generate a link and explain to me how to do this properly?  The  is created and displayed, however the `href` is left blank.  I'm guessing this has something to do with the order of which the link is generated vs when the expression is validated.

`<a *ngIf="(profile$ | async)?.twitter" href="{{ (profile$ | async)?.twitter }}">Twitter Link</a>`

where (profile$ | async)?.twitter = "https://twitter.com/..."

Comment: each async subscribes to the same `this.profile$`. Maybe your observable already completed. Try `<a *ngIf="(profile$ | async)?.twitter as twitterHref" [href]="twitterHref">Twitter Link</a>`. If it still doesn not work, please post your `profile$`

Comment: @htn This worked...thank you for your help.

Comment: @htn.. if you would like to move your response to an answer, I'd love to accept and give you credit for it

Comment: OK. I just added an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each async subscribes to the same this.profile$. Maybe your observable already completed for the second subscription. Try this code to prevent it:

```html
<a *ngIf="(profile$ | async)?.twitter as twitterHref" [href]="twitterHref">Twitter Link</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the `profile$` is a cold observable, each `async` pipe would trigger individual response actions. You could try to wrap the pipe in a `ng-container` to reuse the value.

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="(profile$ | async) as profile">
  <a [href]="profile?.twitter">Twitter Link</a>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: This solution didn't work because it still displayed text from fields with no content.   To clarify, if I remove the content from the `twitter` field in the db, the word "Twitter" still displays, whereas is should not.  The solution offered by @HTN above worked.  Thank you